# Add a blank row or Merge a cell in Webgrid using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

Is it possible to merge rows and columns dynamically based on our condition by using WebGrid. If possible how can i achieve it?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The WebGrid renders as an HTML table. You can use JavaScript to alter that based on cell contents.